# How to structure seqeulize migration files for many-to-many association

Tags: sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

What do you have to put in your migration files (and model files) to create a M:N association in sequelize? I suspect I specifically mean, what `references` need to be set, and what do the required keys in those objects mean, but I'm not 100% sure that's what I mean.

I'm trying to create a users<->rolls association, similar to what was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45050743/is-belongstomany-on-sequelize-automatically-create-new-join-table/55034887#55034887).

Initially, I added `references` to my `user` and `roll` migration files. Then I realised that the `userrolls` join table migration file probably needed `references` the other direction as well. I suspect I'm nearing every possible combination of settings, but somehow still haven't gotten this to work :)

The associations from my model files:

**role.js**

```
static associate(models) {
  models.Role.belongsToMany(models.User, {
    through: models.UserRole
  })
}
```

**user.js**

```
static associate(models) {
  models.User.belongsToMany(models.Role, {
    through: models.UserRole
  })
}
```

**userrole.js**

```
static associate(models) {
  UserRole.belongsTo(models.User, { foreignKey: 'id' });
  UserRole.belongsTo(models.Role, { foreignKey: 'id' }); 
  // UserRole.belongsTo(models.User, { foreignKey: 'userId' }); // <- *
  // UserRole.belongsTo(models.Role, { foreignKey: 'roleId' });
}
```

***** Here, and below, commented out lines are various things I've tried, though they probably don't account for all attempts.

My migration files:

**create-user**

```
'use strict';
module.exports = {
  async up(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    await queryInterface.createTable('Users', {
      id: {
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        /*
        references: {
          model: 'UserRoles',
          key: 'id',
          as: 'userId'
        }
        */
        references: {
          model: 'UserRoles',
          key: 'userId'
        }
      },  
      username: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
      ...
    });
  },
  async down(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    await queryInterface.dropTable('Users');
  }
};
```

The `create-role.js` file is congruent to the above.

**create-user-role.js**

```
'use strict';
module.exports = {
  async up(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    await queryInterface.createTable('UserRoles', {
      /*
      userId: {
        // allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        references: {
          model: 'Users',
          key: 'id'
        }
      },
      */
      userId: {
        // allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        references: {
          model: 'Users',
          key: 'id',
          as: 'userId'
        }
      },
      /*
      roleId: {
        // allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        references: {
          model: 'Roles',
          key: 'id'
        }
      },
      */
      roleId: {
        // allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        references: {
          model: 'Roles',
          key: 'id',
          as: 'roleId'
        }
      },
      createdAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      },
      updatedAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      }
    });
  },
  async down(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    await queryInterface.dropTable('UserRoles');
  }
};
```

I had/have this working, using the standard, [documented method](https://sequelize.org/v7/manual/assocs.html#many-to-many-relationships) where you use `sequelize.define` and rely on `sync` to create the tables, but it seems I can't find the right incantation to get it to work with the `seqeulize-cli` migration method that autoloads all the models. To my (rather untrained) eye, the tables that are generated look right:

```
sqlite> .schema
CREATE TABLE `Users` (`id` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT REFERENCES `UserRoles` (`userId`), `username` VARCHAR(255), `email` VARCHAR(255), `password` VARCHAR(255), `createdAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, `updatedAt` DATETIME NOT NULL);
CREATE TABLE `Roles` (`id` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT REFERENCES `UserRoles` (`roleId`), `name` VARCHAR(255), `createdAt` DATETIME, `updatedAt` DATETIME NOT NULL);
CREATE TABLE `UserRoles` (`userId` INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES `Users` (`id`), `roleId` INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES `Roles` (`id`), `createdAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, `updatedAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`userId`, `roleId`));
```

At least that last entry looks analogous to the PostgreSQL example they give [in the docs](https://sequelize.org/v7/manual/assocs.html#implementation-3), but they don't seem to provide examples of the main tables.

But, no matter what I do, if I go to insert a user, it complains about a foreign key mismatch:

```
Executing (default): INSERT INTO `Users` (`id`,`username`,`email`,`password`,`createdAt`,`updatedAt`) VALUES (NULL,$1,$2,$3,$4,$5);
SQLITE_ERROR: foreign key mismatch - "Users" referencing "UserRoles"
```

I'd take a simple "change this in your code" answer, but, as I mentioned in the beginning, I suspect this is a fundamental misunderstand of what needs to be set and why, so ... some explanation of what I'm supposed to be doing would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need M:N relationship between `User` and `Role` using `UserRole` then `references` option should be used only in `UserRole` because only it has foreign keys to both `User` and `Role`.
Also you should indicate the same foreign keys in `belongsToMany` as you indicated in `belongsTo`:

**role.js**

```js
models.Role.belongsToMany(models.User, {
    through: models.UserRole,
    foreignKey: 'roleId',
    otherKey: 'userId'
  })
```

**user.js**

```js
models.User.belongsToMany(models.Role, {
    through: models.UserRole,
    foreignKey: 'userId',
    otherKey: 'roleId'
  })
```

**userrole.js**

```js
static associate(models) {
  UserRole.belongsTo(models.User, { foreignKey: 'userId' });
  UserRole.belongsTo(models.Role, { foreignKey: 'roleId' });
}
```

**createuser.js**

```js
'use strict';
module.exports = {
  async up(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    await queryInterface.createTable('Users', {
      id: {
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      },  
      username: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
      ...
    });
  },
  async down(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    await queryInterface.dropTable('Users');
  }
};
```

A primary key should be a separate single column as it is in `User` model.
**create-user-role.js**

```js
'use strict';
module.exports = {
  async up(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    await queryInterface.createTable('UserRoles', {
      id: {
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      },  
      userId: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        references: {
          model: 'Users',
          key: 'id'
        }
      },
      roleId: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        references: {
          model: 'Roles',
          key: 'id'
        }
      },
      createdAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      },
      updatedAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      }
    });
  },
  async down(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    await queryInterface.dropTable('UserRoles');
  }
};
```

Comment: OK, I think I get it. And this all seems to work. But, it also seems to work if I leave out the `id` field from **create-user-role**, and use the compound key, as they seem to suggest in the docs. Why do you recommend the separate primary key as a single column?

Comment: AFAIK Sequelize does not support composite keys in associations so it's better to use a surrogate primary key column. If you need to add uniqueness for a pair `userid`-`roleId` you can add a unique index.